# Media Queries Lost with 'Frame Redirect'

Tags: css, redirect, iframe, media-queries

I have a 'vanity site' that redirects to another domain hosted with the same hosting company. It is a frame redirect hence my html becomes enclosed within a frame.

I am finding that when I look at my site on a mobile (via the vanity site) the media queries in my css are not activated. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Where is the external stylesheet being called? In the frame, or outside?

Comment: The style sheet is 'in' the frame. I do not have access to whatever mechanism GoDaddy use to do the frame redirect (i.e. nothing outside the frame)